# Show that $G \backslash \mathbb{R}^3$ from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and ...

Tags: general-topology

Let $G \subseteq \rm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R}^3)$  be the group of all homeomorphisms of the form $f_{(n,m,k)}:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$  where $n,m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $f_{(n,m,k)}(x,y,z)=(x+n, y+m, z+ny+k)$.

Show that $G \backslash \mathbb{R}^3$ with the quotient topology from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and that each point in $G \backslash \mathbb{R}^3$ is contained in an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$

I have been looking at group actions and quotient spaces, as well as properly discontinuous actions, but am having trouble putting this together.

Comment: Look at a small enough ball, say of radius $\epsilon<10^{-10}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  What does $G$ do this ball?  For compactness look at some large compact set in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: How about in terms of group actions such as acting freely, properly discontinuously,...

Comment: In fact, $G\backslash {\mathbb R}^3$ is a compact manifold.

Comment: As  user10354138 already hinted at, to get compactness you just need to find a compact subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the restriction of $\mathbb{R}^3 \to G\backslash\mathbb{R}^3$ to $C$ is still surjective, i.e. such that every orbit intersects $K$ nontrivially.